# Ajaxing function in child class

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, class

I have this classes

```
class mainclass {
     public function __construct() {
            add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_func', array( $this, 'ajax_func' ) );
     }

     public function ajax_func() {

     }  

}
class child1 extends mainclass {

     public function __construct() {

     }

     public function ajax_func() {
            echo "Test child1";
     }  


}
class child2 extends mainclass {

     public function __construct() {

     }

     public function ajax_func() {
            echo "Test child2";
     }  


}
```

every class of the child classes have ajax function `ajax_func()` 
and the jQuery code

```
jQuery.ajax({
         url: 'admin-ajax.php',
         data: {action : 'ajax_func'},
         success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
         }
    });
```

the `console.log` return `Test child1Test child20`
i want to call one of them not all functions in classes 
is there any way to call it like this `data: {action : 'child1.ajax_func'}`?

Comment: Yes, there's a way. Why don't you just check it like `if( $_POST['action'] === 'child1.ajax_func')`?

Comment: @Scorpion I don't understand you , please add more details?